# Extract unicode substrings with the re module

Tags: python, regex, python-2.7

I have a string like this:

```
s = u'something extra BEGIN the unicode text I want with an é END some more extra stuff'
```

I want this text:

```
result = 'the unicode text I want with an é'
```

I've tried to use this code:

```
expr = r'(?<=BEGIN)[\sa-zA-Z]+(?=END)'
result = re.search(expr, s)
result = re.sub(r'(^\s+)|(\s+$)', '', result)  # just to strip out leading/trailing white space
```

But as long as the `é` is in the string `s`, `re.search` always returns `None`.

Note, I've tried using different combinations of `.*` instead of `[\sa-zA-Z]+` without success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The character ranges `a-z` and `A-Z` only capture ASCII characters.  You can use `.` to capture Unicode characters:

```
>>> import re
>>> s = u'something extra BEGIN the unicode text I want with an é END some more extra stuff'
>>> print re.search(r'BEGIN(.+?)END', s).group(1)
 the unicode text I want with an é
>>>
```

Note too that I simplified your pattern a bit.  Here is what it does:

```
BEGIN  # Matches BEGIN
(.+?)  # Captures one or more characters non-greedily
END    # Matches END
```

Also, you do not need Regex to remove whitespace from the ends of a string.  Just use [`str.strip`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.strip):

```
>>> ' a '.strip()
'a'
>>>
```

Comment: This works for me, but what if `BEGIN` and `END` are on different lines.  Sorry I left out that detail!

Comment: You just need to specify the dot-all flag in that case.  You could do: `re.search(r'BEGIN(.+?)END', s, re.DOTALL).group(1)` or `re.search(r'BEGIN(.+?)END', s, re.S).group(1)`.  This will have `.` match newlines.

Comment: ahh, I had been trying to use `re.MULTILINE` without reading the documentation.  Thanks for this, you've been really helpful.